# Речевые стереотипы

Tags: лексика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, примеры речевых стереотипов со словом «второй», «вторая».

Comment: ***Вам зачем?***

Comment: Ребенок выполняет задание,нужно 10 примеров

Comment: Постарайтесь тоже порассуждать, придумать хоть один пример, а иначе ваш вопрос могут удалить. Я не буду голосовать за удаление, мне нравится ваша честность.

Comment: Подобрали следующие примеры: ,,во-вторых..»-введение аргумента, второй голос, второе дыхание, вторая молодость. Правильно ли?

Comment: Зайдите в НКРЯ http://ruscorpora.ru/new/search-main.html и наберите ключевые слова. Выбор за вами.